# HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Access denied for user 'root '@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am working with springboot,mysql and maven.how do l solve that error.below are the contents of the
application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BookStore
  spring.datasource.username=root 
  spring.datasource.password=
  spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
   spring.jpa.show-sql=true
   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`
```

`

Comment: Perhaps a password is required?

Comment: the same error message is coming after putting password;HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Access denied for user 'root '@'localhost' (using password: YES)